# Installing Python 2.x and python 3.x on the same computer

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, theano

There are python 2.7 and python 3.2 on my computer. The default version is 2.7 because using python -V gives 2.7 as the version.

But when I use apt-get install numpy, scipy,pip why it install them into the python3.2 folder. After that I used pip to install the module into the 3.2 folder.

I also installed Theano this way but in the end it showed a message saying that there is no module named Theano installed although it is in the python 3.2 folder.

Comment: I second @erip's suggestion to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). This way, you can explicitly choose which Python version you want to use and install libraries independently without clogging up other versions.

Comment: Agree with comments above. However if you need to install into a specific system installation then use the versioned form of `pip`, e.g. `pip2` or `pip2.7` and `pip3` or `pip3.2`. And/Or the versioned version of `python`, e.g. `python3`.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told on which OS you're running this, but it look likes a debian base linux, maybe ubuntu?

If so, I'd try with:
`sudo apt-get install python3-numpy` or 
`sudo apt-get install python2-numpy`.
This would also work with `python-pip2` and `python-pip3`.

After this, you could effectively use "pip2" or "pip3" to install your packages without having to go through the OS "prebuild" modules (but the os version of the packages are usually my prefered way to install them, if the exists in the repo)

Comment: When i use the commend "sudo apt-get install python2-numpy", the result is :unable to locate package python2-numpy".   by the way, my OS is ubuntu 12

Comment: Ok I see, in ubuntu 12.04 (precise), the package for python2 (numpy) seems to be named `python-numpy` and `python3-numpy` for python3.  For my part I was testing with ubuntu 14.04 (trusty).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing with python, it's often a good idea to run in a virtual environment, this lets you have several different versions of python with several different sets of installed packages on the same system. . .

See http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ for the details.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Anaconda for maintaining two versions of Python. Anaconda  consists of various libraries so you don't have to install them and after switching it to the different version of Python you can easily install them :

1. Download Anaconda for both Python versions
2. Open `.bashrc`
3. Add the path to new Anaconda you have installed for, e.g.:

   ```
   export PATH="/home/paras/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
   ```
4. Now there will be 2 export paths: one for Python 2 and one for Python 3. Comment the one which you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

First install different versions of python or whichever python version you would like to use

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.6 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.3 30
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.4 40
```

Now create virtualenv like this and give the path of python version you want to use inside the virtualenv.

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 <foldername>
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 <foldername>
```